# How to add standard Tabstyle while creating a custom VF Page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where I am creating a custom VF page. I am extending a custom Page 'Custom_Object__c'.

Comment: you need to check your `custom_object__c` which you have used as the tabStyle. Also share the screenshot plz.

Comment: @SFDCGeek please make sure you've assigned a tabStyle for custom_object__c while creating Tab for this object. If you wanted to use Standard Tabstyles you need to use __Tab instead of __c. For more details, please refer : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

Comment: @Vignex : I believe by using tabStyle = "Custom_Object__c", it will fetch the color and other style related to the Custom_Object__c.

But will it fetch the Tab icon also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to specifying tabStyle, you would need to add the following line in your VF page to get the icon and heading.

```
<apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Edit" subtitle="New Contact" />
```

The above line will come after the apex:page part.

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" tabStyle="Contact">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Edit" subtitle="New Contact" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a custom tab for your custom object. This allows you to choose a tab style (color scheme, object logo, etc.). Then add the attribute to the with the name of that tab name to your page component tag. Assuming that you have named the custom tab Custom Object, it would look like this:

```
tabStyle="Custom_Object__tab"
```

Comment: Did you create the custom tab first? It is not the name of the object in the VF attribute but the name of the tab.

Comment: while creating the tab, did you create a Custom Object Tab or a Visualforce Tab? If it is a Custom Object tab, then you need to add the attribute as TabStyle="Custom_Object__c", the __tab is used if the tab was created as a Visualforce tab.